# Extract content from multiple pages of same website

Tags: php, dom

I have this script to extract data from multiple pages of the same website. There are some 120 pages.

Here is the code I'm using to get for a single page.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/product?page=1');

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($links as $link){
    file_put_contents('products.txt', $link->getAttribute('data-product-name') .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

How can I do it for multiple pages? The links for that specific pages are incremental like the next page will be `https://www.example.com/product?page=2` and so on. How can I do it without creating different files for each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
function extractContent($page)
{
    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/product?page='.$page);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
        // skip empty attributes
        if (empty($link->getAttribute('data-product-name'))) {
            continue;
        }
        file_put_contents('products.txt', $link->getAttribute('data-product-name') .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

for ($i=1; $i<=120; $i++) {
    extractContent($i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However I encounter another issue, getting empty lines in the txt file. How can I remove them before saving them?

Comment: Also this doesn't stop unless I stop the php process.

Comment: The function is called 120 times. Change this value according to your needs. To remove empty lines you can test the content of the attribute before writing it. See my edit